# Are my old stock certificates worth anything? How can I find out?

Tags: stocks, share-certificate

I have a old stock certificate that my great grandmother bought.  It's for two shares from the Dallas/Fort Worth Airport National Bank, dated 1973. That bank has merged multiple times and is now part of Wells Fargo.

I  wonder how this works and if the two shares are  worth anything. Would it be worth my time to search and find out?  Please let me know if you can help me figure this out.

Answer (score 5):

If the bank was ultimately merged into Wells Fargo, then [Wells Fargo Investor Relations office](https://www.wellsfargo.com/about/investor-relations/) should be able to help you. Their phone number and e-mail address are at the bottom of their website.

Answer (score 4):

Check the certificate to see if the Transfer agent's name is listed on it.  Perhaps even the address.  If so, contact them and see what those two shares represent today.

Plan B would be to see customer service at Wells Fargo and see if they can assist you in determining what, if anything, these shares are worth.

Answer (score 2):

Plan C, if the certificates have the kind of fancy engraving that was common on such documents at the time, might be to see if there are any collectors who might be interested -- either collectors of printed material, or collectors of things associated with that company or that kind of company.

(I have some old sheet music that I rescued mostly because I liked the cover art... still need to figure out how to display it. And where.)

Comment: Shares might be worth $5, and someone is willing to pay $50 for a nicely framed certificate to hang it on the wall. How many certificates do you have?