# Do Old Florida Rum Company stock certificates issued in 1962 have any current value?

Tags: share-certificate

My husband was given 100 shares of the Old Florida Rum Company by his father in 1967. The original company is closed, but there is a current company operating under the same name.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are my old stock certificates worth anything? How can I find out?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/121019/are-my-old-stock-certificates-worth-anything-how-can-i-find-out)

Comment: Might be a collector; old stock certificates are often very pretty pieces of paper, and there's the obvious theme.

Comment: Even if the shares still trade, the 55 year old share certificates are artwork/antiques/both and might be worth more.