# We found share certificates of the Preferred stock from Waconia Creamery Association Waconia MN first one dated 1943 -1958. Are they worth anything?

Tags: shares

Waconia Creamery Association gave the farmers that sold milk to the creamery shares in the business.  It might have been a Co-op. We think the creamery was part of Waconia Farm Supply. Later it was sold to possibly United Farm Supply.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are my old stock certificates worth anything? How can I find out?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/121019/are-my-old-stock-certificates-worth-anything-how-can-i-find-out)

Answer (score 2):

Looking at [this](http://herald-journal.com/farmhorizons/2010/waconia-farm.html), the company was called "Waconia Farm Supply" in 2010.

> In 1966, the Waconia Creamery Association Board of Directors decided to close the creamery, and they began reorganizing the cooperative to continue only their farm supply department. After leasing the creamery building to several different businesses, the building was sold in 1974, and by 1975, the cooperative officially was named Waconia Farm Supply.
>
> ...
>
> As of Sept. 1, 2010, merged with Hennepin Cooperative and have taken over the day-to-day operations. Locations include Maple Plain, Dayton, and Rush City, which is a c-store only.

There are some contacts mentioned [here](http://www.minnesotahorsemensdirectory.com/waconia/waconia-farm-supply.php) and [there](https://www.farmershotline.com/users/9524422126). Try to give them a call.